# C# WebBrowser Control - for some pages I get a blank screenshot

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, webbrowser-control, screenshot, snapshot

In DocumentCompleted event handler, I try to take snap shots of certain pages, for some pages, the snapshot is perfectly taken, BUT, for other pages (e.g. the last page) a blank snapshot is taken, despite the fact that in the Browser WinForm I see content in the page!!! any idea what might be the problem?

I am trying to Capture snapshot of my WebBrowser control using the following code:

```
    private void GetSnapshot(string nameSuffix, ImageFormat format)
    {
        string dateTimeNow = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt");
        string imageName = string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}.{3}", websiteName, nameSuffix, dateTimeNow, format);

        using (var bmp = new Bitmap(ieBrowser.Width, ieBrowser.Height))
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation("Saving screenshot to '{0}'", imageName);
            ieBrowser.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, ieBrowser.Width, ieBrowser.Height));
            bmp.Save(imageName, format);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by creating a new dummy thread, make it wait for a few seconds and then return. (so the Control thread is not blocked).

turns out that webbrowser needs a small amount of time to actually render the page after final DocumentCompleted event is fired

Comment: Why create a dummy thread for this? You could do `await Task.Delay(1000)`. Or, at worst, something like `for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { Application.DoEvents(); Thread.Sleep(100); }`